# Check mandatory dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, html

Before activating the ajax and sending data to webmethod in C# i need to check if some values are filled in(mandatory).
There is a hidden column in my tabe that has values true or false, and I have written jquery loop to check them if the textbox in their row are mandatory or not. This works fine.
Now I have to do the same for 3 drop down fields(Product Level1, Level2 and Level3).
I managed to write some code but it's not working good, alert's are chaotic.
First when button is clicked code needs to check mandatory texbox fields in the table then it has to check if all 3 drop down's are filled in, and then to fire ajax.

This is my table and code:

https://jsfiddle.net/m8dLwf9z/53/

Here the jquery part:

```
$(function () {

            $(".IDMandatory").each(function (i, el) {
                if ($(el).text().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
                    $(el).closest("tr").find("input,select").prop("required", true);
                }
            });


            $("#myButton").on("click", function () {

                var ok = true;              

                $("[required]").each(function () {
                    $(this).css("border", ""); // reset
                    if (!$(this).val()) {
                        ok = false;
                        $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
                        var message = ""; 
                        if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL1").val() == 0) {
                            message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 1 field!";
                        }
                        if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL2").val() == 0) {
                            message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 2 field!";
                        }
                        if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL3").val() == 0) {
                            message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 3 field!";
                        }
                        if (message != "") {
                            alert(message);
                        }
                    }

                });




                if (ok) {

                }
                else {
                    alert("Fill in the remaining mandatory fields!");
                }
            });
        });
```

I think the problem is here:

```
var message = ""; 
                        if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL1").val() == 0) {
                            message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 1 field!";
                        }
                        if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL2").val() == 0) {
                            message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 2 field!";
                        }
                        if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL3").val() == 0) {
                            message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 3 field!";
                        }
                        if (message != "") {
                            alert(message);
                        }
```

Can someone please help me with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is not with the `message+=` code but rather than `$("[required]").each(function () {` - you're mixing explicit checks (by looking at named/id'd elements) and general handling `$("[required]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your message construction out of the $("[required]").each(function ()) should do the trick.

```
    $(function () {

        $(".IDMandatory").each(function (i, el) {
            if ($(el).text().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
                $(el).closest("tr").find("input,select").prop("required", true);
            }
        });


        $("#myButton").on("click", function () {

            var ok = true;              

            $("[required]").each(function () {
                $(this).css("border", ""); // reset
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    ok = false;
                    $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
                }

            });

            var message = "";

            if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL1").val() == 0) {
                        ok = false;
                        message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 1 field!";
                        }
            if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL2").val() == 0) {
                        ok = false;
                        message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 2 field!";
                        }
            if ($("#MainContent_ddlProductHierarchyLvL3").val() == 0) {
                        ok = false;
                        message += "Plase fill in the GPR PIM Product Hierarchy Level 3 field!";
                        }
            if (message != "") {
                        alert(message);
                            }

            if (ok) {

            }
            else {
                alert("Fill in the remaining mandatory fields!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
This works fine but there is one problem. When the fileds in table are filled in and the three ddl's then it should fire ajax :/
Now ajax fires when only fields from table are filled in. I made an alert to simulate the ajax:
https://jsfiddle.net/m8dLwf9z/74/
Can you help?

Comment: @freej17 If you want the ajax fires only when required fields and ddls are filled in, you can set ok to false when each of ddl's value is 0. Please see edited code snippet.

Comment: Thank you very mush !
This work's really good, there's only one more minor thing left.
alert mandatory fields is fired even if they are filled in at the table :/

Comment: Thank you for your effort ! :)
I will try to fix the last problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate select box with this: https://jsfiddle.net/thecreativedev/m8dLwf9z/63/

```
 if ($("select[name='ctl00$MainContent$ddlProductHierarchyLvL1']").val() == 0) {
    message += "Plase fill in the Product  Level 1 field!";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay ! but the code should first check all the filleds in table if they are filled in at the same time, next it should check the 3 drop downs, and then when this is all ok then fire ajax. I updated the snippet. Now the problem is ajax fires when only fileds in the table are checked, it's not waiting the drop downs check.
https://jsfiddle.net/m8dLwf9z/74/
Can you help ?